# Installing geopandas with anaconda prompt causes ImportError

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, geopandas, keyerror

I am aiming to analyse geodata in python but fail on step 1: the installation. I'm relatively new to python and used to installing packages with pip. Now, for geopandas, it looks like I'm supposed to use conda install. Sadly, I get an error.

What I did: I downloaded the most recent anconda software and typed 'conda install geopandas' in the anaconda prompt (anaconda3).

Reading similar questions online I saw some questions solved by updating anaconda, but since I downloaded the version on the homepage I would expect it to be up to date. Also, I didn't find any entries with error code similar to mine.

From what I gather from the response, anaconda didn't even manage to find the package (first line of the below code). However, I am not very experienced in the analysis of error code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**The error-code**

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1213): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 261, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
    index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
    reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 276, in get_reduced_index
    new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 98, in query_all
    create_cache_dir()
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 674, in create_cache_dir
    cache_dir = join(PackageCacheData.first_writable().pkgs_dir, 'cache')
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 152, in first_writable
    pkgs_dirs = context.pkgs_dirs
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 520, in pkgs_dirs
    fixed_dirs += user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME),
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
    path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
    from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1211, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 238, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 261, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 276, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 98, in query_all
        create_cache_dir()
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py", line 674, in create_cache_dir
        cache_dir = join(PackageCacheData.first_writable().pkgs_dir, 'cache')
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 152, in first_writable
        pkgs_dirs = context.pkgs_dirs
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 520, in pkgs_dirs
        fixed_dirs += user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME),
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
        path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
      File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
        from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified module could not be found.

`$ D:\Programs\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py install geopandas`

  environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

Comment: This looks like a corrupted installation of anaconda. I would try reinstalling it. I guess it does not install any package, right?

Comment: You are right, it is not installing any package (not even anaconda clean). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but the error prevails.
(installation directory: D:\Programs\anaconda3)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue back then, and I followed the instructions on this link.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fastest-way-to-install-geopandas-in-jupyter-notebook-on-windows-8f734e11fa2b

Basically what this does is create a new environment in your anaconda navigator where I could get geopandas working normally.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, Step 1 of your guide doesn't work for me  as the command "conda create -n geo_env" also leads to errors. Even "conda info" does so. I will open a new thread asking for help with conda in general I guess.